# JS Drag and Drop image URL

Tags: javascript, html, url, drag-and-drop

Hi I'm building a image uploader so I can insert images into my blog articles, I have a form that does all my image uploading then I'm displaying the images in my create an article page via URL saved to the database. What I'm trying to do is build a drag and drop to select the image from the page and ondrop get the url on that image so I can save it to the data base and save the url into my articles table. So what I need is the URL of the image when its dropped in the drop box so ill be able to save the url in the database for in my articles table. Heres my code, thanks for any help in advance!

PHP/HTML

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM images";
    $i = 0;

    if($data = query($sql)) {

        while($image = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
        ?>
        <div class="layout-column four">
            <img id="drag<?php echo $i++ ?>" src="<?php echo $image['file_name']?>" alt="<?php echo $image['description'] ?>" ondragstart="drag(event)">
        </div>
        <?php

    }

<div id="drop" class="layout-column twelve" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function allowDrop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

var drop = document.getElementById('drop');
document.write(drop);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function drop(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault(); 
    var imageUrl = evt.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');

    var rex = /src="?([^"\s]+)"?\s*/;
    var url, res;

    url = rex.exec(imageUrl);
    alert(url[1]);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tLLKq/1/)

Comment: @ime Can you provide me an example page with image?

Comment: sorry, that was midtake.... and one other thing, if we change the regex to (/\ssrc="?([^"\s]+)"?\s*/).. it will be better, because in google images there is other information which have 'src='. So we must need to get only that src which have space before... :)

Answer (score 0):

`event.dataTransfer.getData('text/html')` can be used to get the HTML of the dropped image. Then, [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) can be used to read the source of the image, which works both for images on the page and images dropped from other sites.

Demo:

```js
let dropArea = document.getElementById('dropArea');
dropArea.addEventListener('dragover', e => e.preventDefault());
dropArea.addEventListener('drop', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let html = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
  let src = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html")
              .querySelector('img').src;
  console.log(src);
});
```

```html
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/00ff11/000000&text=Drag+Me" draggable>
<div id="dropArea" style="height: 100px; background: dodgerblue; text-align: center;">Drop here</div>
```